# Google Maps with height=100% and margin top

Tags: css, google-maps, fullscreen, margin

I'm coding a wordpress plugin that should display a fullscreen google map. If you are logged in in WordPress, a Toolbar is displayed at the top using margin-top. Google Maps apparently needs a div with height=100% to display a fullscreen map, but if you are logged in and the admin toolbar of wordpress is displayed, I have unnecessary scrollbars. Absolute positioning is not possible because of a floating sidebar and mobile support.

All the solutions for the "100% with margin" problems either use absolute positioning or "min-height", which is not working for google maps. Anyone has a solution for me?

Comment: `height: calc(100% - 100px)` being 100px the size of the toolbar. works? and if you want it full height you can do also `height: calc(100vh - 100px)`

Comment: `height: calc(100vh - 100px)` worked for me, thank you very much! With `calc(100% - 100px)` I still had a 100px wide margin at the bottom (and of course scrollbars)

Comment: adding as an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it full height of the viewport just do `100vh`.

So we remove the size of the bar.

`height: calc(100vh - 100px)`